# How to access ListFragment Adapter within a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have an app that downloads data which must be displayed within the fragments of a `viewpager`. I dont know how to call the `ListFragment` `adaptername.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `AsyncTask` that does the data download.

**For example say i am downloading the temperature forecast for the next seven days:**

my app has the following structure:

- `MainActivity`: Starts an `AsyncTask` to download the data in `onCreate()` and gives the user choice (`button`) of which day to look at. Clicking the button launches `SecondActivity` and passes the day index to the `ViewPager` (to set the current view).

[image: MainActivity User Selection]

- `SecondActivity`: Contains a `ViewPager` that contains 7 of the same `ListFragments` (The list display the temperature over a period of 5 hours, so the list has 5 entries).
- `MyListFragment`: when this loads it sets the `adapter` to display each temperature (If the data is downloaded) otherwise it sets the temperature to `"loading..."`

Now my problem is, if the user waits on the `MainActivity` until the data downloads they can then proceed to the `ViewPager` to see the `ListFragment` temperatures without problem. **But if they try click a day and load the** `ViewPager` **before the download completes the fragments will forever just say** `"loading..."`

I need a way that I can reload the adapter within the `ListFragment` from the `onPostExecute()` of my `AsyncTask` in `MainActivity`. To do this though i need to be able to actually access the `ListFragment` that the `ViewPager` is displaying. How do update the adapter `onPostExecute()`?

---

**MainActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    new LoadData().execute();
}

protected class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Download happens here
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //I need to tell the viewpager in SecondActivity to reload the ListFragment it is currently showing here
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private int[] temperatureArray;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int[] defaultTemps = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    temperatureArray = getIntArrayExtra("temps", defaultTemps);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerID);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(intent.getIntExtra("page", 0));
    mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ...
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyListFragment lf = new MyListFragment();
        lf.setTemperatures(temperatureArray);
        return lf;
    }
}
```

I need a way to be able to refresh the current displayed fragment when i finish downloading in the AsyncTask.

Comment: Can you show some of your actual code? It's hard to tell exactly what you mean

Comment: Ive added some code just to demonstrate what im doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest doing one of two things, not sure if these are best practices.

You can Have the AsyncTask send a broadcast with a unique action when it has finished loading the information. That would of course have to be done from OnPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {     
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            //_Do whatever action you normally do, like storing result to database.
            //fire up the broadcast
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.ACTION_FEED_LOADING_FINISHED);
            mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
}
```

And then intercept that via a BroadcastReceiver on your Fragment's code.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(ACTION_FEED_LOADING_FINISHED)) {
            //The AsyncTask Finished loading data
        }
    }
};
```

Once the event is received, since the BroadcastReceiver is in the Fragment, where the views are loaded, you can refresh your UI accordingly.

Or,

You can pass the View you want to refresh as a paremeter on your AsyncTask.

Imagine your AsyncTask class like this:

```
private static class getInternetStuffTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
```

Then you can create a custom constructor to receive the view as paremeter:

```
public getInternetStuffTask (final Context context, final ListView list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListView= list;           
    }
```

Then, during onPostExecute, when data is loaded, you can simply set the adapter to the ListView directly form the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

You're touching on two different problems. First, [use a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231971/async-task-started-and-ended-in-different-activities) for downloading. Services are there for long running operations (like a download) that live outside an Activity's lifecycle.

Second, to [communicate between Activities and Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) you'll want to use an callback interface. The link provided is to the docs which do an excellent job of explaining and providing samples.